# AWS EKS Ingress - No Address

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a kubernetes application using AWS EKS. With the below details:

Cluster:
 + Kubernetes version: 1.15
 + Platform version: eks.1

Node Groups:
 + Instance Type: t3.medium
 + 2(Minimum) - 2(Maximum) - 2(Desired) configuration

[Pods]
 + 2 active pods

[Service]
 + Configured Type: ClusterIP
 + metadata.name: k8s-eks-api-service

[rbac-role.yaml]
    https://pastebin.com/Ksapy7vK

[alb-ingress-controller.yaml]
    https://pastebin.com/95CwMtg0

[ingress.yaml]
    https://pastebin.com/S3gbEzez

```
When I tried to pull the ingress details. Below are the values (NO ADDRESS)
Host: *
ADDRESS:
```

My goal is to know why the address has no value. I expect to have private or public address to be used by other service on my application.

Answer (score 1):

solution fitted my case is adding ingressClassName in ingress.yaml or configure default ingressClass.

> add ingressClassName in ingress.yaml

```
#ingress.yaml
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
...

spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx       <-- add this
  rules:
...
```

or

> edit ingressClass yaml

```
$ kubectl edit ingressclass <ingressClass Name> -n <ingressClass namespace>



#ingressClass.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"   <-- add this
....
```

[link](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/ingress/ingress_class/)

Answer (score 0):

In order for your kubernetes cluster to be able to get an address you will need to be able to manage route53 from withtin the cluster, for this task I would recommend to use externalDns.

> In a broader sense, ExternalDNS allows you to control DNS records dynamically via Kubernetes resources in a DNS provider-agnostic way.

source: [ExternalDNS](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns)

Comment: Hi I am getting the below error for the same case where I see no address for the host of ingress. Desperately looking for a solution. 

{"level":"error","ts":1643650856.9675832,"logger":"controller-runtime.manager.controller.ingress","msg":"Reconciler error","name":"app-ingress","namespace":"backend","error":"WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials\ncaused by: RequestError: send request failed\ncaused by: Post \"https://sts.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/\": dial tcp: i/o timeout"}

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me too that after all the setup, I was not able to see the ingress address. The best way to debug this issue is to check the logs for the ingress controller. You can do this by:

1. Get the Ingress controller po name by using: kubectl get po -n kube-system
2. Check logs for the po using: kubectl logs <po_name> -n kube-system

This will point you to the exact issue as to why you are not seeing the address.